# How to get innerHTML content from a loaded element made by .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Here it is

part.html :

```
    <div id="header">
        Hello Mars
    </div>
```

full.html :

```
    <div id="inj">
    </div>

    $('#inj').load("part.html #header"); 
    alert(document.getElementById("header").innerHTML); <-- this part is not working
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to check the loaded content, you need to do it like:

```
$('#inj').load("part.html #header",function(){
  alert(document.getElementById("header").innerHTML); 
});
```

check http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

the load command is asynchronous you have to wait for the content to load before reading it.

`load` can have a callback function parameter that is executed when the request completes.

```
$('#inj').load('part.html', function() {
    alert(document.getElementById('inj').innerHTML);
});
```

or since you are using jQuery instead of `getElementById`:

```
$('#inj').html()
```

Comment: So How can I get the value from the ID? Can you show me A code?